# R: mclapply run it through a loop

Tags: r, parallel-processing, cluster-computing, mclapply

I am trying to run mclappy which loops over 2000 times. I was wondering if there is a way to make it more efficient as the code breaks on AWS SageMaker after it reaches 150

The code is:

```
mclapply(1:2500), myfunc, mc.cores=4)
```

myfunc has the function in it. But is there a way to split it into clusters and spin off the code in chunks. I am new to this and makeClusters is something which I am unable to understand at this point.

What I mean is prospective solution to this:

```
mclapply(1:150), myfunc, mc.cores=4)
mclapply(151:300), myfunc, mc.cores=4)
mclapply(301:450), myfunc, mc.cores=4)
.
.
.
.
mclapply(1850:2000), myfunc, mc.cores=4)
```

Comment: This is already the way it is done, the `mc.preschedule` (default TRUE) parameter breaks the data into chunks.  If you want to use a cluster, `parLapply` is the function you want to use, and it also splits the data.

Comment: Is parLapply more efficient than mcapply? How would the parLapply code look for this particular case?

Comment: They have different uses.  `mclapply` is for local multi-threading only.  If you need to use a cluster, use `parLapply`.  `cl <- makeCluster(...<arguments...); parLapply(cl, 1:2500, myfunc); close(cl)`